# Why does changing parent class empty input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle class on a parent element (div / form, either). My CSS changes the visibility of some form elements based on that parent class.

When the class is updated on the div / form all the inputs in the form are emptied / changed to no value. The functionality is OK on most of the inputs but for the ones that are always visible, I don't want to lost the value when hiding the form.

Basically, I've got a basic search form and an advanced one.

EDIT: Vanilla JavaScript (not jQuery) works as expected... WHY jQuery?

```
var d = document.getElementById("div");
d.className = d.className + " advanced";
```

Here's the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/psalmody/Lsnsaups/2/

CSS:

```
#div .search-advanced {
  display:none;
}

#div.advanced .search-advanced {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div">
<form id="searchForm">
<fieldset>
  <div>
    <label for="term">Semester:</label>
    <select id="term">
      <option disabled></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="subj">Subject(s):</label>
    <input type="text" id="subj"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="search-advanced">
    <label for="crse">Course Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="crse" maxlength="5">
  </div>
  <div class="search-advanced">
    <label for="sec">Section:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sec" maxlength="3">
  </div>
  <div class="search-advanced">
    <label for="crn">CRN(s):</label>
    <input type="text" id="crn">
  </div>
  <div class="search-advanced">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#advanced').click(function () {
        $('#div').toggleClass('advanced')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `<button>` with type `reset`, which will set all the form's controls to their initial value. From the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#reset-button-state-(type=reset)):

> The input element represents a button that, when activated, resets the
>   form.